# How to sort the date column in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C#.This is my code.

```
    private const string ASCENDING = "ASC"; 
    private const string DESCENDING = "DESC";
    public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection 
    {     
        get     
        {         
            if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)             
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;          
            return (SortDirection) ViewState["sortDirection"];                     
        }     
        set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }  
    }

    public string SortExpression
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["sortExpression"] == null)
                ViewState["sortExpression"] = "JobNumber";
            return ViewState["sortExpression"] as string;
        }
        set { ViewState["sortExpression"] = value; }
    }
    protected void OnSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
            SortExpression = e.SortExpression;
            if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
            }
            else
            {
                GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            BindGrid();
    }
```

I am applying sorting for all the columns and working fine. But with date column it is like in this order(dd/mm/yyyy).

- 30/11/2012
- 10/12/2012
- 9/10/2012

  ```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportedDate" HeaderText="Reported Date" SortExpression="ReportedDate" DataFormatString="{0:DD/MM/YYYY}" HtmlEncode="false" />
  ```

the datatype of this column is date.

How to do this?Am i doing wrong?

Comment: in your code "30/11/2012" and other dates are considered as string and only string sort is taking place .

Comment: thanks..yeah i understood that but i dont know why string sorting is happening.I am declaring this as a date type only..can u give me any hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options

1.To sort at SQL Level,this is the best and proper method,bind the resulting resultset in to gridview.

2.To bind a DataTable with the query output and run a sort on datatable,and then bind it to gridview.
 keep in mind to add datatype to datatable column `accTable.Columns.Add("Date",typeof(DateTime));`

Comment: Yeah..ok i am binding by first method like directly binding the resultset to grid.any idea about why string sorting is happening?

Comment: first method means something like 'select * from RecentLogin order by the_date',after tat you just have to bind it,why are you sorting again ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of this column in database? It seems that it is like a string field instead of a DateTime field. If this is the case, you need to fix the datatype first then you can get the right sorting order without changing anything on the gridview.

Try to change

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ReportedDate" HeaderText="Reported Date" SortExpression="ReportedDate" DataFormatString="{0:DD/MM/YYYY}" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

to

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="ReportedDate">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:label id="lblDate" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("ReportedDate", "{0:DD/MM/YYYY}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Like i specified in post it is the type of date.

Comment: Did you try to change BoundField to TemplateField ?

Comment: thanks..but it didnot work just same as previous.Is my codebehind is ok?