# Date columns will not sort on Gridview filled from DataTable

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am using [this](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/176_Sorting_GridView_Manually_.aspx) example to sort GridView loaded from DataTable.   I also reviewed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817737/how-to-sort-the-date-column-in-gridview?rq=1) - I used sajanyamaha advice by adding columns to DataTable and that's when GridView's date columns starting sorting properly with one peculiarity.  I have 11 columns, first column is a selectcommand that redirects to another page. I have no boundfields or template fields, gridview is filled from datatable in code behind.

The problem is sorting and paging work fine on all columns EXCEPT the 2 Date columns.  The Date columns, ReviewDue and SubmittedDate.  They sort correctly but they do not retain the sort order while paging.  GridView will reset to page 1 at each sort column change   which causes the user to never see past page 1 when Date column is sorted.  The issue I am trying to resolve and understand is why do all the other columns function correctly but the Date columns behave differently? What custom handling is needed to get date columns to behave like the other string or int columns?

I have googled plenty but I don't find anything with this oddity.

Here is my pertinent code.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["SortExpr"] = "EPRID";
                ViewState["SortDir"] = " DESC";

                if (blnIsAdmin == true || blnIsManager == true)
                {
                    BindData(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    //redirect
                    Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPages/AccessDenied.aspx");
                }
            }
        }


        private void BindData()
        { 
                GridView1.DataSource = this.GetData();
                GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        private DataTable GetData() 
        {
            string cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM ….ORDER BY " + ViewState["SortExpr"].ToString() + " " + ViewState["SortDir"].ToString();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("EPRID", typeof(Int32));
            table.Columns.Add("FormName", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("Completed", typeof(Boolean));
            table.Columns.Add("Sup1", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("Sup2", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("Sup3", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("ReviewDue", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("SubmittedDate", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("SubmittedBy", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("DocID", typeof(Int32));

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    //get all EPRs (unfiltered grid)
                    if (blnIsAdmin == true ")
                    {
                        cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM … ORDER BY " + ViewState["SortExpr"].ToString() + " " + ViewState["SortDir"].ToString();
                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdStr, conn))
                        {  
                            da.Fill(table);
                        } 
                    }
                    else if (blnIsManager == true)
                    {
                        cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM… WHERE user = @user …ORDER BY " + ViewState["SortExpr"].ToString() + " " + ViewState["SortDir"].ToString(); 

                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdStr, conn))
                        {
                            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@user", Value = strCurrentUser, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Size = 50 });
                            da.Fill(table);
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
            return table;
        }
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            //go to page 1 when sorting
            GridView1.PageIndex = 0;

            string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

                if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                    SortGridView(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
                    ViewState["SortDir"] = " DESC";
                }
                else
                {
                    GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                    SortGridView(sortExpression, ASCENDING);
                    ViewState["SortDir"] = " ASC";
                }

            ViewState["SortExpr"] = sortExpression; 
        }
private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
        {   
            ViewState["SortExpr"] = sortExpression; 
            ViewState["SortDir"] = direction;

                //get unfiltered grid
                DataTable dt = GetData();    
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt); 

                dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;

                GridView1.DataSource = dv;

                GridView1.DataBind(); 
        }  
        public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
        { 
            get
            { 
                if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null) 
                    //ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Descending; 
                return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"]; 
            } 
            set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; } 
        } 

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {    
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; 
            BindData();  
        }
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" 
            Caption="List of awaiting or completed employee performance reviews" 
            PageSize="25" 
            onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" 
            onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
            CellPadding="4" 
            DataKeyNames="EPRID,DocID" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
            onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" 
        CssClass="GridStyle"  >
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="Black" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"  />  
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            <PagerStyle  ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Why are you sorting in database and DataView both ? Either one will be fine right ?

Comment: You do not need to do this `DataView dv = new DataView(dt); dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;` since you already have sorted the data when you call `GetDate()` and the sorting has been done in the database level.

Comment: You're both correct I do not need DataView (I am still learning) anyway when I remove dv, the sort of Date columns reverts to sorting by month-day instead of Year-Mo-Day.  I tried putting the following in RowDataBound() event but it doesn't change the behavior: `e.Row.Cells[8].Text = Convert.ToDateTime(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["ReviewDue"]).ToString("d");//s`  It just makes the date values look pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Part of the issue was with the `SELECT` statement in the view that was used in Sql query strings' FROM clause, `cmdStr` (details of this were left out of my original question for brevity-possibly my first error in getting proper help?). In the views' `SELECT` statement, the 2 datetime columns were constructed like this:

```
,Convert(varchar(10),NextReview,112) as ReviewDue
,Convert(varchar(10),SubmittedDate,112) as SubmittedDate
```

and should have been simply:

```
,NextReview as ReviewDue
,SubmittedDate
,etc...
```

(BTW it made no differnce which standard I used, 101, 110, 111, 112...). Also  the corresponding data types in the  DataTable's `Add()` method should match as `DateTime`in `GetData()`.  Finally I added a condition and modified the `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL inline query, `cmdStr` to:

```
//pass ViewState to variable for use in cmdStr when DateTime columns are sorted on
    strExpression = ViewState["SortExpr"].ToString();

        if (strExpression == "ReviewDue" || strExpression == "SubmittedDate")
            {
             cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM vwView ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, " + strExpression + ", 120) " + ViewState["SortDir"].ToString();  
            } 

        else
        {
        //use original cmdStr
        }
```

In the gridviews `_RowDataBound()` event I also formated the date to show Date part only in the grid like this:

```
//ReviewDue will never be null
        e.Row.Cells[8].Text = Convert.ToDateTime(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["ReviewDue"]).ToString("d");

                //SubmittedDate can be null, handle null 
                object dtmDate9 = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["SubmittedDate"];

                if (dtmDate9 == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[9].Text = String.Empty;
                }
                else
                {

                    e.Row.Cells[9].Text = Convert.ToDateTime(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["SubmittedDate"]).ToString("d");
                }
```